# property exists

Tags: php

This code:

```
 $_post = &get_post($post->ID); 
 $classname = ($_post->iconsize[0] <= 128 ? 'small' : '') . 'attachment';
```

sometimes produces this error:

```
[Sun Apr 15 08:51:35 2012] [error] [client 180.76.5.150] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$iconsize in /srv/www/virtual/myblog.com/htdocs/wp-content/themes/mimbo/attachment.php on line 8
```

I would like to modify the line to add the property_exists check on the property and default to '' if it doesn't exist but am a little unfamiliar with the syntax dealing with properties.  How would the line look?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `isset`:

```
if(isset($_post->iconsize)) {
    // ...
}
```

So:

```
<?php
$_post = &get_post($post->ID);
$classname = (isset($_post->iconsize) && $_post->iconsize[0] <= 128 ? 'small' : '') . 'attachment';
?>
```